# Trigger for nested element

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, label, tooltip

```
<Label.ToolTip>
    <StackPanel Name="tTipTxt">                                    
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="15" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Run Text="" Name="tTipBody"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Label.ToolTip>
```

This is the `ToolTip` I would like to display when my mouse is over a `Label`. How can I create a `Trigger` to stop the `ToolTip` from displaying itself if the `ToolTip` text is empty or null?

I have tried this XAML piece:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Content"
                 Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Content"
                 Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But I still need to get into the deepest stack to get the correct target for the text change. Could you help add some more steps to get this done for me?

Comment: You need to use a `ControlTemplate` for the `ToolTip`, then you can set your `Triggers` using `SourceName`s and your `Setter`s using `TargetName`s.

Comment: or you could use `DataTrigger` and bind to the Target using `ElementName` binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `Style` for `Label` that disables the `ToolTip` using the `AttachedProperty` `ToolTipService.IsEnabled`

Example:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Content" Value="">
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This will hide the `ToolTip` on the `Label` when the Label `Content` is `Null` or `Empty`